# wrong value returned while getting value of dynamically created textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've dynamically added some rows to my ASP.NET table using JavaScript, my rows contain textboxes (which are in fact spans), it is my textbox HTML which as added to my table:

```
               var spanCount = document.createElement("span");
           spanCount.innerHTML = "<input style=\"width:30px\" type=\"text\" name=\"count\" value=1>";
```

later I change default value of this textbox (default value is 1), and I want to get current value of this dynamically created textbox using JavaScript, I use following code to get its value, but I always get 1 (default value), I want to have current value of this textbox:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=tblFoodList.ClientID %>').rows[1].cells[3].firstChild.innerHTML);
```

but I get following HTML (I can parse its value):

```
<input style="width:30px" name="count" value="1" type="text"
```

as you can see, value="1", but I have changed value, is there any way that I can get current value (or HTML) of this span?

Comment: where are you examining the HTML after the change? And what browser are you using?

Comment: Where did you specified id "tblFoodList" for textbox?

Comment: I use firefox, tblFoodList is name of my ASP.NET table, my textbox (span) is in a cell of my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` to get the text value of an input.

Assuming your structure:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=tblFoodList.ClientID%>') // this is your table
  .rows[1] // second row
  .cells[3] // third column
  .firstChild // the span you created
  .firstChild // the input
  .value // the value of the input
);
```

Comment: I get nothing when I use textContent instead of innerHTML

Comment: use value instead of textContent.

Comment: also, note the two `firstChild`s, because you need the value of the input, not the span.

Comment: thanks Saml, your answer worked great! Now I get the current value and also don't need to parse HTML! thanks